# React-Native: each child in array should have unique key even when I include the key

Tags: react-native

I just started `React-Native` and I came across a problem while dealing with the `map` of array.As it needs a unique key for all elements.
I have specified the key in the render method but I am still getting the warning.
Here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text , ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import AlbumDetail from './AlbumDetail'
export default class AlbumList extends Component {
  state = {albums: ['Fetching Data...']};
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('fetching data');
    // Make a request
    axios.get('http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
      .then(response => this.setState({albums: response.data}));
  }
  renderAlbums() {
    return this.state.albums.map(album =>
      <AlbumDetail
        key = {album.title}
        album = {album}
      />
    );
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <ScrollView>
        {this.renderAlbums()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the warning I receive even after including the key

```
ExceptionsManager.js:73 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `AlbumList`. See https://fb. me/react-warning-keys for more information.
    in AlbumDetail (at AlbumList.js:16)
    in AlbumList (at index.js:21)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at index.js:19)
    in FirstApp (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your error. Its saying the error is in the render call of AlbumList. The code you specified is fine.